# Toddler does not like that baby is staring on him

Tags: toddler, fighting

My toddler (2.5 years old) does not like when baby (6 months) looks at him.
And complains about it.
A friend told me it is common for toddlers to want to poke baby's eyes.

What is the cause of this? and
what is recommended way to get him not to worry about it?

(I did not find a duplicate of this question)

Comment: It seems he either takes it as disrespect, as the baby showing authority, best advice I found was when the toddler complains to tell the toddler to touch the baby's nose and make a "boomps" noice, (that makes it into a joke and shows himself that he is not scared of the baby)

Comment: Can you edit the question with more information about the circumstances when this happens, how the children act and what complaints the toddler has?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why a toddler would be unhappy about having a baby stare at them.

I do know that for your toddler, their life has been turned up side down with the arrival of baby.  Your toddler had the adults all to themselves, but now they have to share, and 2 year olds are not known for being good at sharing.

As for what to do, often we can redirect a young child by making something into a game.  For example, racing a child to their bed when it's bedtime, where we sometimes win and other times we let them win, and this makes it a game.

Many families play games about staring at each other, so it might help to introduce a staring game to see if it helps your toddler focus on the game instead of their dislike for the baby staring.